# Discover/scan SONOS speakers on network

Tags: sonos, ssdp

I'm currently working on a control app for SONOS, and I'm able to control sonons groups, which is linked to my users household.

However; I'd also like to be able to control speakers on the network I'm currently on, regardless of whether they are linked to my account or not.

I can see that eg. Spotify has this feature, but I cannot find any documentation on the sonos developer page about discovering speakers/groups on the same network.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63264663/how-to-scan-for-sonos-speaker-on-same-wifi-network) old post about the topic, which speaks about SSDP search, but doesn't really conclude anything.

Am I looking in the wrong place, or simply not understanding the sonos documentation?